# Is there a reason for any C or C++ compiler to not define wctrans_t and wctype_t as the type wchar_t?

Tags: c++, c, widechar

Actually, I'm working on a comparison of data types between programming languages, and here is my problem when reading the C and C++ standards.

Quoted from C11,

> `wctrans_t` is *a scalar type* that can hold values which represent locale-specific character mappings
>
> `wctype_t` is *a scalar type* that can hold values which represent locale-specific character classifications

The phrase ***a scalar type*** indicates that C11 does not restrict `wctrans_t` and `wctype_t` to be a specific scalar type.

My GCC 4.8 of MinGW implements `wctrans_t` and `wctype_t` as a typedef for `wchar_t`, and I can't think there is a reason for any other C compilers to not define them as it is.

Could somebody proof otherwise, or give a possibility for that to happen?

Comment: Maybe one could have `wchar_t` being UTF-16 two-bytes short numbers, even if most compilers don't do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am surprised someone defined them as `wchar_t`, neither `wctype_t` nor `wctrans_t` have anything to do with characters.

Both platforms I use define them as something else:

```
aix~$ grep wctype_t /usr/include/*h | grep typedef 
/usr/include/ctype.h:   typedef unsigned int    wctype_t;

aix~$ grep wctrans_t /usr/include/*h | grep typedef 
/usr/include/wctype.h:typedef wint_t (*wctrans_t)();


solaris~$ grep wctype_t /usr/include/*h | grep typedef 
/usr/include/wchar.h:typedef    int     wctype_t;

solaris~$ grep wctrans_t /usr/include/*/*h | grep typedef
/usr/include/iso/wctype_iso.h:typedef unsigned int      wctrans_t;
```

Comment: @chux my point is that `wchar_t` is irrelevant (but if you're curious, it's not typedef'd on C++ builds and is typedef'd on C builds to unsigned int/unsigned short and int/long, respectively, depending on whether I'm building 64-bit or 32-bit)

Answer (score 4):

Cubbi has already answered this question.  Here a couple of additional informations, because the definition of the standard, is not really self-explaining.

A wctype_t represents locale-specific character ***classifications***.  So its not about characters, but about their classification (aka. the old isalpha(), isalnum(),..).  The wctype_t values are used by the function iswctype() to test a wide character.  Example (C11,  section 7.30.2.2.1):

```
iswctype(wc, wctype("alnum")) // iswalnum(wc)
iswctype(wc, wctype("alpha")) // iswalpha(wc)
iswctype(wc, wctype("blank")) // iswblank(wc)
iswctype(wc, wctype("lower")) // iswlower(wc)
...
```

Similarly, a wctrans_t represent  represent locale-specific ***character mappings***.  So it' not about a character code set, but it is mappings from one type of wide characters to a related tone (e.g. like the old toupper(), to lower(),...).  The mappings are described in section 7.30.3 of C11 standard), here some examples:

```
towctrans(wc, wctrans("tolower")) // towlower(wc)
towctrans(wc, wctrans("toupper")) // towupper(wc)
```

The wchar_t definition that you mentions seems misleading to me, although, a wchar_t is an integer too.

Here the way it is defined in MSVC13:

```
typedef unsigned short wint_t;
typedef unsigned short wctype_t;
typedef wchar_t wctrans_t;     // yes, here too !
```

Comment: Apart from your comment, I think the C11 statement that says both `wctrans_t` and `wctype_t` are scalar types has a too broad meaning because scalar types can also be `float`, boolean, string, etc. It is better to say they both are integer types.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  On the other side the standard says "Arithmetic types and pointer types are collectively called scalar types." which gives some freedom to the implementers.  For insance, one could perfectly imagine an implementation in which these two types would be some kind of pointers.

Comment: @Cristophe, What? :-( BTW, +1, thanks for the surprised fact. :-)

Comment: If you don't mind, would you update your answer to include the AIX `wctrans_t` definition?

Comment: I'm so sorry. I means @Cubbi.

Comment: @Cubbi, it turns out you had already include the AIX `wctrans_t` definition. Sorry for inconvenience. Could somebody here with higher authotiry delete my comments because it need not to be exist.